# Pandas dataframe from column to row

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to extract data from excel:

```
PN = df.iat[6,8]
LF = df.iloc[79:151,8].to_list()

d1 =  {"PN":PN,"LF":LF}
d3=pd.DataFrame(d1)
print(d3)
```

This is what it prints:

```
                      PN        LF
0   105222331-04  1DJ    -0.002429
1   105222331-04  1DJ     0.002642
2   105222331-04  1DJ     0.006156
3   105222331-04  1DJ     0.009979
4   105222331-04  1DJ     0.010492
```

I want to make it look like this:

```
 PN                  LF          LF         LF
105222331-04  1DJ    -0.002429   0.002642   0.006156
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create one row DataFrame by join lists:

```
L = df.iloc[6, [8]].tolist() + df.iloc[79:151,8].tolist()

d3 = pd.DataFrame([L])
```

Duplicated columns names are not recommended, because problem with select, but possible:

```
L = df.iloc[6, [8]].tolist() + df.iloc[79:151,8].tolist()
cols = ['PN'] + ['LF'] * (len(L) - 1)
d3 = pd.DataFrame([L], columns=cols)
print (d3)
```